# how to track your time spent debugging in vs 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, time-tracking

Is there a plug-in for Visual Studio 2010 that automatically tracks your time spent debugging ? I found a tool called "VSTime Beta", but it's designed to work with VS 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any such plugin, but you can easily write a [macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx) that does that for you.

The macro can simply record current time and start the debugger, then when the debugger finishes record how much time was spent debugging.

You can assign <kbd>F5</kbd> to this macro as well.

Answer (score 1):

The only tool I'm aware of is the VSTime plugin.  While it is targeted to 2008 it's a straight forward open source plugin that should work just as well in 2010.  The source code is available here

- http://vstime.codeplex.com/

It should be as simple as

- Get a copy of the source
- Upgrade the installer project to support 2010